# Lorentz Transformations derivation

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames

I was reading derivation of Lorentz transformation but I don't understand why the constant a here is equal to -c^2.

Full pdf: [http://www2.physics.umd.edu/~yakovenk/teaching/Lorentz.pdf](http://www2.physics.umd.edu/%7Eyakovenk/teaching/Lorentz.pdf)

[image]

Comment: "If $a<0$ we can write this as $a=-c^2\,.$" What is wrong with that?

Comment: I mean, why did we give the value c^2. a is unknown constant?

Comment: [_Wikipedia_'s take on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivations_of_the_Lorentz_transformations#Using_group_theory) (in which $\kappa:=1/a$) notes _we can set_ $c=1/\sqrt{-\kappa}=\sqrt{-a}$. It's a definition of $c$, not a claim about $a$.

Comment: If we only look  at that fragment in isolation, $a$ and $c$ are unknown constants. Read on and find out what they say about them later. I have no idea and don't want to look at that pdf for you.

Comment: Okay, your attention is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

It's just maths, not physics. If $a$ is less than zero, then $a=-b$ where $b>0$. If $b>0$ then $b=c^2$ where $c=\sqrt b$. I haven't looked at the PDF but it appears to be using some sort of symmetry-based arguments to derive the Lorentz transformations.